# Wsgi is installed but "Module mod_wsgi does not exist!"

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I want to install the wsgi module (using Flask) with apache2, on a Vagrant vm.

Activating module provided errors :

```
09:52 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

(env)
[09:56 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ sudo a2enmod mod-wsgi
ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!

(env)
[09:57 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ sudo a2enmod mod_wsgi
ERROR: Module mod_wsgi does not exist!
(env)
```

So, I check the installation :

```
[09:55 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ dpkg -l libapache2-mod-wsgi
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-============================================-===========================-===========================-=============================================================================================
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi                          4.5.2-1+deb.sury.org~xenial amd64                       Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

I want to (re)install it :

```
[09:57 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ (sudo) pip install mod_wsgi
The directory '/home/vagrant/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/vagrant/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/37/dd336068ece37c43957aa337f25c59a9a6afa98086e5507908a2d21ab807/mod_wsgi-4.6.4.tar.gz (2.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.6MB 1.5MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-g9YSf2/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 168, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g9YSf2/mod-wsgi/
```

What's "apxs" ?, it's the http companion for wsgi ?

The list of apache's actives modules is here :

```
$ sudo apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
 ...
 wsgi_module (shared)    <-----------
 ...
```

So, it's fine

The module is on the right place :

```
[10:36 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
(env)
[10:38 ]-[vagrant@vm]-[/etc/apache2/mods-enabled]
$ ll /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 223K mai    3  2016 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so*
```

I read some tutorials, and, I think :), I do right :)

Thanks a lot.

Fabrice

Comment: What is in the mods-available directory?

Comment: There's "wsgi.load" (see above) and "wsgi.conf" (all the lines are commented)

Comment: You should be using ``a2enmod wsgi``. If you separately want to use ``pip install mod_wsgi`` as different way of installing mod_wsgi, instead of system mod_wsgi package, read the system requirements properly on https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/. There you will see it tells you that you need to install appropriate dev package for Apache. You need that for ``apxs``.

Comment: If using ``pip install mod_wsgi``, you should uninstall system mod_wsgi package as they are two completely different ways of installing it.

Comment: ok. So, I just want to use the mod_wsgi for apache (not python module). I understand I do not have to install python's module :). For now, the "ERROR: Module mod_wsgi does not exist!" is still here.

Comment: If you are using system ``libapache2-mod-wsgi`` package, the command is ``a2enmod wsgi`` not ``a2enmod mod_wsgi`` and not ``a2enmod mod-wsgi``. What command are you running.

Comment: ok, thanks. It's fine now.